# Excel VBA Hyperlinks.address

Tags: excel, vba

First, I am using code from here:
' Credit to Trent Kelly, OpenStax-CNX module: m17228
' Link: https://cnx.org/exports/f8ba6f20-7586-4449-b44e-e62fb2deff31@3.pdf/hyperlink-search-and-replace-in-microsoft-excel-3.pdf

The code searches a workbook for a specified hyperlink and changes it to a new value (in my case use to fix broken/changed links)

```
Dim LinkURL As String
Dim PreStr As String
Dim PostStr As String
Dim NewURL As String
Dim FindPos As Integer
Dim ReplaceLen As Integer
Dim URLLen As Integer
Dim MyDoc As Worksheet
Dim MyCell As Range
Dim WS As Worksheet

'On Error GoTo ErrHandler

For Each WS In Worksheets

    Set MyDoc = ActiveSheet

    For Each MyCell In MyDoc.UsedRange
        MsgBox MyCell.Value, vbOKOnly, "Debug"
        If MyCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            LinkURL = MyCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address            'MyCell.Address(rowabsolute, columnabsolute)
            FindPos = InStr(1, LinkURL, FindString)
                If FindPos > 0 Then 'If FindString is found
                    ReplaceLen = Len(FindString)
                    URLLen = Len(LinkURL)
                    PreStr = Mid(LinkURL, 1, FindPos - 1)
                    PostStr = Mid(LinkURL, FindPos + ReplaceLen, URLLen)
                    NewURL = PreStr & ReplaceString & PostStr
                    MyCell(1).Hyperlinks(1).Address = NewURL 'Change the URL
                End If
        End If
    Next MyCell
Next WS
```

The area I am having an issue is here:

```
If MyCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
          LinkURL = MyCell(1).Hyperlinks(1).Address
```

The `hyperlinks.count` works perfectly at detecting whether there is a hyperlink.
If the hyperlink is a `"mailto:"` for example, the second line of the code also works.
BUT  If the hyperlink references something inside the workbook (another worksheet/cell then `MyCell(1).Hyperlinks(1).Address` just returns "" every time.

I have also tried `MyCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address`, but it seems that the `MyCell` variable is still on the correct cell (I have used `"MsgBox MyCell.Value, vbOKOnly, "Debug""` to check the value).

I have looked all over and cannot find a reason why I am not able to return the hyperlink address.

Comment: A hyperlink to another location in the workbook uses .Subaddress, not .Address.

Comment: u/Jeeped: You nailed it!   Added an IF statement to handle both cases and its GTG.  Many thanks!

Comment: Also, sorry if this is a duplicate.  I honestly searched but couldn't find this issue.  I'll look harder next time!